# Two ASP.NET GridView controls on same website: When clicking Gridview3 then GridView1 is fired (SelectedIndexChanged)

Tags: gridview, aspxgridview, selectedindexchanged

I am writing a website which shall read data from a MySQL database. The GridView3 shows a list of the tables in the DB. By clicking (left mouse click) a table shall be chosen and the contents of that table shall be shown in GridView1. By clicking GridView1 a specific dataset is chosen for further processing.

The latter works perfectly. But on clicking GridView3 GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged is fired, not as expected GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged. I find this behavior very strange, and I have no idea to avoid that.

I found the described behavior by setting breakpoints in the code behind. I was expecting that on clicking Gridview3 the code would stop at Gridview3_SelectedIndexChanged but it stopped at breakpoint in GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged.

Has anyone an idea how to fix that problem?

Here some part of my code (GridView3 was renamed to grdMotSeriesTables):

<asp:GridView ID="grdMotSeriesTables" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="LightGray" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" Font-Names="arial" Font-Size="Smaller" Width="1092px" />

Whatever I try the SelectedIndexChanged event is not fired.

Comment: Please share some code to understand your problem